# app shutsdown on onclick in androidstudio using kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

am new in kotlin, i am just now making my first code app

there are 2 inputs & 1 button on which i set onclick sum
(i just drag & drop 2 inputs & 1 button, Don't have much knowledge because i have just started kotlin)

**Mainactivity.kt**

```
package com.example.hello

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }


    fun sum (view: View){
        var a = number1.toString().toInt()
        var b = number2.toString().toInt()

        var result  = a + b
        textView2.text="Result: $result"

    }
}
```

problem is when i click on sum button, my app automatically shuts down

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-82dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-24dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:hint="+"
        android:onClick="sum"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/number2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/number2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="281dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number2"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sum" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number1"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

am getting this error in debugs section:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hello, PID: 23117
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
```

Comment: There's not enough in your code to see what the problem is. Maybe show us the full code and the stacktrace for the error.

Comment: @LoremarMarabillas i have updated question, please check

Comment: Can you show your activity_main.xml file?

Comment: @Tenfour04 i have added please check

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, it's hard to see what is wrong but I guess that number1 and number2 are views/EditTexts? in that case toString won't give you the text of those but instead a description of the object which for example could look like this:

```
"EditText:{ someinfo, 40183}"
```

And when you call toInt() on that String, kotlin doesn't know how to convert it and your app crashes.

Instead (if number1 and number2 are edittexts)

try:

`number1.getText().toInt()`

Comment: sorry but it didn't work, & i also updated question please check may be this time its more clear

Comment: Hi, the log you provided is too short unfortunately. There is often something more meaningfull after the first couple of lines. Especially if anything is marked in blue (your files) you should see the line that causes it

Comment: And perhaps the xml file could also be related

Comment: The error is in the sum function. The sum function is called through `android:onClick="sum"` in xml. When the sum function throws any form of exception it displays the exception just as shown above.

Comment: @LoremarMarabillas i have pasted my main_activity.xml file code, please check

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's a NumberFormatException.

### Solution:

```
    fun sum (view: View){
        var a = number1.text.toString().toInt()
        var b = number2.text.toString().toInt()

        var result  = a + b
        textView2.text="Result: $result"

    }
```

You need to call `text` first to get the actual value in the input View. Calling `toString` on `number1` and `number2` will give you the string representation of these objects which is most likely a short description of the object and most likely not a number, hence, the NumberFormatException.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work, actually in source file the code is same as yours. But when it didn't work so i changed it little bit with the above one.